# MouseLeave triggers when ContextMenu opens

Tags: wpf, window, mouseleave

My application has a `AlwaysOnTop` behavior and I want it to lose focus when the mouse leaves it. There are some buttons with context menu. The issue is that the moment the a `ContextMenu` opens the `MouseLeave` event automatically fires, even if the mouse is still on a child of my window, it instantly closes since I set focus to other external application

```
private void This_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (!this.IsMouseOver)
    {
        OtherExternalWindow.Focus();
    }
}
```

I have tried adding a check if the mouse is not over, but it seems that the context menu is not considered a child of my window (?). I think this could be achieved by naming all my ContextMenus and checking if any of them are open, but I would like to avoid this approach unless it is impossible other way.

How to switch focus at mouse leave but not to break context menu behavior?

Comment: The ContextMenu is not a child of your window. It is kind of a window itself. So when the mouse moves over the ContextMenu it actually leaves your window.

Answer (score -1):

I you don't want the ContextMenu to get the focus, set its (and its inner elements such as MenuItems) `Focusable="false"`.

```
<Button Content="BBBB">
    <Button.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu Focusable="False">
            <MenuItem Header="AAAA" Focusable="False"/>
        </ContextMenu>
    </Button.ContextMenu>
</Button>
```

Comment: This does not work for me. The MouseLeave event is still triggering and taking the focus out of the context element.